# MySQL error 1022 when inserting. How to fix?

Tags: mysql, insert, mariadb

I have very strange problem with my MariaDB Database.
I am using it in pair with [gorm](https://gorm.io/)
When I try to make an insert request to one of the tables I receive error

> Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'titles'

Ok. I try to use the same code directly from Navicat or Datagrip and MAGIC - everything is working and record inserting. I have checked foreign keys - all have unique names, but I still don't know how even model this.

Definition of table

```
/*
Navicat MariaDB Data Transfer

Source Server         : My Hetzner
Source Server Version : 100316
Source Host           : 127.0.0.1:3306
Source Database       : sovet_api

Target Server Type    : MariaDB
Target Server Version : 100316
File Encoding         : 65001

Date: 2020-05-09 18:46:52
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for titles
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `titles`;
CREATE TABLE `titles` (
  `anime_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `anime_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anime_name_rus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ai_help` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pidor_ban` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `vk_new_template_sub` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `vk_new_template_dub` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_name_template_sub` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `video_name_template_dub` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `video_desc_template_sub` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_desc_template_dub` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `telegram_new_template_sub` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `telegram_new_template_dub` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `telegram_sub_group_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT -1001269855704,
  `telegram_dub_group_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT -1001269855704,
  `vk_banned` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `command_sub_id` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `command_dub_id` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `default_preroll_id_sub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_watermark_id_sub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_preroll_id_dub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_watermark_id_dub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vk_sub_group_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT 33905270,
  `vk_dub_group_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT 33905270,
  `vk_album_id_sub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vk_album_id_dub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repost_sub_vk_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `repost_dub_vk_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `default_sub_add_att` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_dub_add_att` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `gdrive_parent_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gdrive_torrent_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gdrive_sub_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gdrive_font_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ai_search_enabled` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `nyaa_scan_enabled` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `anime_shiki_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anime_name_jpn` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anime_rating` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anime_episodes` int(255) DEFAULT 0,
  `hashtags` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscribe_sub_enabled` smallint(6) DEFAULT 0,
  `subscribe_dub_enabled` smallint(6) DEFAULT 0,
  `subscribe_priority` smallint(6) DEFAULT 0,
  `sub_purse` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dub_purse` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_qiwi` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dub_qiwi` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_paypal` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dub_paypal` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`anime_id`),
  KEY `command_sub_id` (`command_sub_id`),
  KEY `command_dub_id` (`command_dub_id`),
  KEY `default_watermark_id_sub` (`default_watermark_id_sub`),
  KEY `default_watermark_id_dub` (`default_watermark_id_dub`),
  KEY `default_preroll_id_sub` (`default_preroll_id_sub`),
  KEY `default_preroll_id_dub` (`default_preroll_id_dub`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDX__titles__anime_name_search` (`anime_name`,`ai_help`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDX__titles__anime_name_search_bot` (`anime_name`,`anime_name_rus`,`ai_help`),
  CONSTRAINT `titles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`command_sub_id`) REFERENCES `command` (`command_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `titles_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`command_dub_id`) REFERENCES `command` (`command_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `titles_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`default_watermark_id_sub`) REFERENCES `watermarks` (`watermark_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `titles_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`default_watermark_id_dub`) REFERENCES `watermarks` (`watermark_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `titles_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`default_preroll_id_sub`) REFERENCES `prerolls` (`preroll_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `titles_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`default_preroll_id_dub`) REFERENCES `prerolls` (`preroll_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_hash_gen`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_hash_gen` AFTER INSERT ON `titles`
FOR EACH ROW
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM title_hashtags
         WHERE hashtag_value =    TRIM(BOTH '_' FROM
             REGEXP_REPLACE(NEW.anime_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+','_')))
    THEN
        INSERT INTO title_hashtags(anime_id, hashtag_value)
            VALUES (NEW.anime_id, TRIM(BOTH '_' FROM
             REGEXP_REPLACE(NEW.anime_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+','_')));
END IF
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The SQL-code

```
INSERT INTO `titles` (`anime_id`,`anime_name`,`anime_name_rus`,`pidor_ban`,`vk_new_template_sub`,`vk_new_template_dub`,`video_name_template_sub`,`video_name_template_dub`,`video_desc_template_sub`,`video_desc_template_dub`,`telegram_new_template_sub`,`telegram_new_template_dub`,`telegram_sub_group_id`,`telegram_dub_group_id`,`vk_banned`,`vk_sub_group_id`,`vk_dub_group_id`,`vk_album_id_sub`,`vk_album_id_dub`,`default_sub_add_att`,`default_dub_add_att`,`gdrive_parent_id`,`gdrive_torrent_id`,`gdrive_sub_id`,`gdrive_font_id`,`anime_shiki_id`,`anime_name_jpn`,`anime_rating`,`anime_episodes`,`subscribe_sub_enabled`,`subscribe_dub_enabled`,`subscribe_priority`,`sub_purse`,`dub_purse`,`sub_qiwi`,`dub_qiwi`,`sub_paypal`,`dub_paypal`,`ai_search_enabled`,`nyaa_scan_enabled`)
    VALUES ('1046','Urashimasakatasen no Nichijou Special','Деньки Урасимасакатасэн: Школьная пора — Эпизод 13','0','','','','','','','','','0','0','0','0','0','56053731','56053731','','','1-SHGDPX_ybF0Kqu0rtLKcnY_rmfsXa96','1WmRjv8fsZAAY2uBGoRx76Ar1B8rJGKcj','1TvlCnAQ6DbLR3WWiePDCJerYNEwX09oW','1nZRP4Yf92DyuyeOPtW44_vzZLENN6gs6','40921','','','0','0','0','0','0','0','','','','','0','0')
```

But when I try to use THE SAME SQL in datagrip, navicat or smth other - it works

Thank you!

Comment: Then its not the same code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to help us help you. Show us the definition of your table, and the SQL you use to try to INSERT or UPDATE the  row. This error says your table is defined so that some column in your table has a UNIQUE or PRIMARY index on it, and you're trying to put a duplicate value in that column.

Comment: I modified. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about not doing the `IF...SELECT`; simply do `INSERT IGNORE ...`.

Or maybe `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`